# ¿Cómo genero un archivo de Word con Ruby? Linux

Tags: linux, ruby

Necesito saber cómo generar un archivo de *Word* con *Ruby*. Soy un programador principiante.

Ya creé un proyecto, pero no sé en qué carpeta generarlo. ¿En modelo vista o controlador?

Answer (score 0):

Nunca he tenido la oportunidad de usarlas, pero podrías probar con [htmltoword](https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword) que, como su nombre lo indica, te transforma código html en word. Otra opción es [caracal](https://github.com/trade-informatics/caracal) que te permite generar tu documento programáticamente.
¿En que carpeta generarlo? eso es bastante debatible y creo depende de tu problema específico y lo que quieras realizar (descargar el documento, enviarlo por email, simplemente almacenarlo para uso posterior, etc), sin embargo, si estás aprendiendo, creo que si el dejar tu código en el controlador, modelo o en `lib/`, es el menor de tus problemas.

Ahora, de mi consideración personal, si tienes la oportunidad de elegir, te recomendaría ENCARECIDAMENTE que generaras archivos `pdf` en vez de `doc/docx`, ya que aparte de ser un formato bastante mas accesible de leer que el de Word y verse más profesional para el usuario final, tiene gemas mucho más robustas y con más soporte como [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) o [Wicked pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf).